# User only get three chances to enter a valid value

Tags: python, loops

Adding a loop such that the user gets three chances to enter a 
valid value. If the user enters an invalid value more than three times in a row, the program 
should issue an error message and exit

In python please
I know how to do the while loop, but how do you make it to only three times

What I have:

```
miles= eval(input("Enter a value for miles "))
kilometers= miles * 1.6 
while miles < 0: 
    print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles")
    miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
```

Comment: You can do this with a while loop too. You just need an invalid_counter variable and do checking on that.  But in any case what have you tried? What's the status of your current code?

Comment: this is what I have                                                          miles= eval(input("Enter a value for miles "))
kilometers= miles * 1.6
while miles < 0:
 print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles")
 miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))

Comment: @DesiBoy Can you add that code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fix your code first...you're evaluating "miles < 0" after you convert it to kilometers, so whether or not the user corrects the miles variable, you already have the resulting kilometers variable.

```
miles= eval(input("Enter a value for miles ")) 
kilometers= miles * 1.6 
while miles < 0: 
   print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles") 
   miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
```

change to:

```
miles = eval(input("Enter a value for miles ")) 
while miles < 0: 
    print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles") 
    miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
kilometers= miles * 1.6 
print(kilometers)
```

You can add a counter to your while loop to take note of iterations, and stop when it goes over:

```
counter = 0
miles = eval(input("Enter a value for miles ")) 
while miles < 0: 
    print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles") 
    miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
    counter+=1
    if counter > 2:
       break
kilometers= miles * 1.6 
print(kilometers)
```

And make it so that the kilometer variable only displays if the counter doesn't exceed:

```
counter = 0
miles = eval(input("Enter a value for miles ")) 
while miles < 0: 
    print("Error, you can't enter a negative value for miles") 
    miles = eval(input("Enter the correct value for miles "))
    counter+=1
    if counter > 2:
       break
if counter <= 2:
  kilometers= miles * 1.6 
  print(kilometers)
else:
  print("Exceeded error count")
```

Comment: thank you, I see what you did here. for some reason it does it 4 times. and how do you make the program to "exit"?

Comment: Four times because it gives 3 chances *after* the first input. Change to `counter > 1` and `if counter <= 1:` if you want it to strictly be 3 times, including the initial input. Not sure what you mean by exit though, since there is no need for it: The program stops after printing kilometers or saying "Exceeded error count"

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem (because i already faced up a long time ago)

I find my solution myself... don't give up just face it ...i done this same....
Ohh sorry we are taking about your problem,not mine
...

Here a solution....`

```
for i in range(3):
   pwd = float(input('enter password '))
    if pwd == 123456:
        #your work 
        #my recommended (function)
    else :
        i += 1
        print("wrong password")
        if i == 3:
            print("wrong password limit exeded")`
```

I done for password u can edit that line to input

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python programmer but I can help you regarding to the logic behind it.

first declare a global variable for example integer. something like.

```
int invalid= 0;
```

Then do the loop using a do while statement or likewise loop.

```
while (true)
{

}
```

inside your while statement, put a validation on it or your logic and also the checking of number of iteration (not valid). something like

```
while (true)
{
 bool valid = isthisValid(); // your method
 if (valid == false)
  {
     invalid = invalid+ 1;
     if (invalid >= 3)
     {
      // Throw your error here!
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achive this. Here are two:

Using a for loop. And two check conditions:

```
import sys

def isvalid(input):
    if input == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for n in xrange(3):
    check = isvalid(input(">>"))
    if check == True:
        break
    elif check == False and n == 2:
        sys.exit("Exceed tries")
    else:
        print "Wrong input, try again"

print "Right"
```

Using a while loops and a counter: ( I prefere this )

```
import sys

def isvalid(input):
    if input == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

mistakes_counter = 0
while True:
    check = isvalid(input(">>"))
    if check == True:
        break
    else:
        mistakes_counter += 1
        if mistakes_counter == 3:
           sys.exit("Exceed tries")
        print "Wrong input, try again"

print "Right"
```

Comment: `"Wrong input, try again"` this shouldn't print if it's the 3rd attempt

Comment: It's minor bug, anyway fixed :)